# Squeaking Brake Noises

Tags: brake-rotor, brake-pad

My dad gave me his 2014 2014 Honda Cr-v with over 80K miles. I'm not good with cars and I'm hearing squeaking noises when hitting the brakes. Does that mean that my brake pads and rotors need replacement?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know is to look at the pad thickness.

Some pads have harder bits that can cause noises at times.

If the rims have slots or holes then you may be able to see, if not then you have to remove the wheels to check.